# creating a pandas dataframe from a list first I create a dictionary then convert that to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list that I have converted to a dictionary and want to convert the dictionary to a pandas dataframe.

My attempt is below however I am getting the following error:

> 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

```
**df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
```

**Sample of Data:**

```
{'AAM': 2,
 'ABC': 5,
 'ABP': 3,
 'ABU': 1,
 'ACL': 3,
 'ACX': 6,
 'ADA': 7,
 'ADE': 2,
```

Here are the functions I have used to attempt to create the dataframe. The last line is causing the issue.

> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')

```
def list_to_dict(a_list):
    results = {}
    for i in a_list:
        i = str(i)
        if len(results.keys())==0: 
            results[i] = 1
        else:
            if i not in results.keys():
                results[i] = 1
            else:
                results[i] = results[i] + 1

    return results

flatten = df.mentions.tolist()
combined = [item for sublist in flatten for item in sublist]
a = list_to_dict(combined)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
```

Comment: Can you add sample of data which return error?

Comment: from this information I would conclude that `pd` is of type `numpy.int64`. Are you sure you're not overwriting `pd` in your code somewhere?

Comment: For me it works perfectly if `a` is sample `dict`.

Comment: added sample data and code, I don't believe I am overwriting pd anywhere

Comment: If use small sample of data it still return error? Sample of data is `a` ?

Comment: Yes a is a dictionary and I've tried different dictionary of smaller size everything still returns that error.

Comment: Hmmm, if use `pd.DataFrame([a])` still same error?

Comment: Hmm why would adding the single duct to a list have any effect. If you can create a dataframe directly from a list maybe the trouble I'm going to in order to create a dictionary first Is not required

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want the key and value as two columns or are you trying to do something else? If the former, this is all you need:

```
pd.DataFrame(a.items())
```

Comment: Yes please I'd like the key and values as separate columns. So two columns in the resulting dataframe

Comment: Thanks very much A.kot I will

Comment: Upvote. Nice clean solution, but I think you might need to convert the `dict_items` `a.items()` to a list. Like `pd.DataFrame(list(a.items())`

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the dict as in your sample you could do two list comprehensions:

```
d = {
    'AAM': 2,
    'ABC': 5,
    'ABP': 3,
    'ABU': 1,
    'ACL': 3,
    'ACX': 6,
    'ADA': 7,
    'ADE': 2
}
pd.DataFrame([[item for item in d.keys()],[item for item in d.values()]])
```

Result is a dataframe with you data

```
     0  1
0  ADA  7
1  ACX  6
2  ABU  1
3  AAM  2
4  ABC  5
5  ACL  3
6  ABP  3
7  ADE  2
```

Comment: this seems like it should work as I want both the keys and the values of the dictionary so two columns in the dataframe. However I am still getting the above error: 
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-215-632e4c8cdf3a> in <module>()
      2 combined = [item for sublist in flatten for item in sublist]
      3 a = list_to_dict(combined)
----> 4 data = pd.DataFrame([[item for item in a.keys()],[item for item in a.values()]])
      5 data

AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Comment: @yoshiserry if your `a` is indeed a dictionary, and `pd` is the `pandas` library then both mine and A.kot's solutions works. I think you've somewhere in your code overwritten `pd`.

Comment: if I have overwritten pd. in my code then it would be a syntax problem, I.e. it wouldn't know what DataFrame() was if I didn't have pd.DataFrame() - it needs the alias I have given to the pandas library. I will continue to review my code to see if I have overwritten the reference to the pandas library.

Comment: @yoshiserry let me know what you find